# Regular expression to return full file name and path

Tags: regex, excel, vbscript

I'm a bit rusty when it comes to regular expressions so I could really use some expert help for the syntax.  I'm looking for a regular expression that will **return the full file name and path** from a string.  I am using the reference "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" for Excel 2010 VBA.  I just need the regex string.

Here's an example of what I'm working on.  If the string is

> =VLOOKUP($X18, 'E:\BUDGET 2012-13\Round 2 - final\program worksheets[AD allocations Support 2012 R2.xlsx]2013'!costcenter,
>   Y$5+2, FALSE)

then the returned value would be

> 'E:\BUDGET 2012-13\Round 2 - final\program worksheets[AD allocations
>   Support 2012 R2.xlsx]2013'

OR

> 'E:\BUDGET 2012-13\Round 2 - final\program worksheets[AD allocations
>   Support 2012 R2.xlsx]

( I can code around either return value ).
Thank you!

**-- DOH! --**

I figured it out a few minutes ago.  Being a newb I can't answer my own question so I'm doing it here -- some of the rules here are odd...anyway...  The syntax is

> '.+?'

and will return

> 'E:\BUDGET 2012-13\Round 2 - final\program worksheets[AD allocations
>   Support 2012 R2.xlsx]2013'

*If you know of a better way please feel free to post it.*

Comment: you can answer your own question in time so that it doesn't stay open or delete it since the regex is fairly simple and there is not much reference value to it, i'm glad you found it

Answer (score 0):

copy from my regex toolbox:
`'([a-zA-Z]:\\(?:[^\\/:*?"<>|#]++\\)*+)([^\\/:*?"<>|#]+)'` 
I have tested your data with http://regexr.com?31oaq, you will get path from group 1, file name from group 2. I hope this can help you :)